# Will GCM give new tokens on old clients using GCM after its deprecation

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Google has deprecated GCM as of April 10, 2018, and according to the documentations, will stop supporting GCM by April 11, 2019.

There has been a lot of Q/As about the topic and it has been mentioned that old tokens will continue to work for existing users, but my question is whether new users will be able to obtain **new tokens** using GCM after April 11?

So basically I have an application released with the old gcm codebase, using old versions of google play services, distributed in another market (not Play Store). As of now, installations get their GCM tokens and they are working as expected, what happens to a new user installing my (old) application after the deprecation? I don't plan on updating the application for now.

Thanks!

Comment: Your existing Android app will continue to receive FCM notifications. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850761/do-i-need-to-migrate-gcm-to-fcm-on-client-side/53853335#53853335

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What about new tokens? In short, what happens for new installations of my old app?

Comment: Same thing, they will still be able to receive notifications. My linked answer names the two things that won't be possible anymore.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You've updated your answer in the linked you referred to and added a third point: "New installations of your existing GCM-using app **may not** be able to get a token". So will new installations of the previous application versions not work anymore?
This is an important issue but for some reason it's really hard to find a clear answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

> new users will be able to obtain new tokens using GCM after April 11?

Simple answer NO

But your original question is :

> Will GCM give new tokens on old clients using GCM

Simple answer YES

Google has replaced GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) with FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

They no longer support the old GCM user interface for new users. Existing users can still use the old GCM interface but newly created keys will not work for Android messaging post 4/11/2019.

However, GCM and FCM registration tokens are mutually interchangeable; you can send to existing GCM tokens through the FCM HTTP server APIs.

Reference : 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq

Comment: So, basically this means if I have an old application which I don't plan on updating, new users won't be receiving GCM tokens and my app is dis-functional? I Have to update my app, develop new versions and have it released so new users would install that newer version? [I don't want to change my ApiKey/SenderID or anything else]. Thanks

Comment: Client SDKs and GCM tokens will continue to work indefinitely. 
If you are working with a platform that implements GCM it will still work too. However, you won't be able to target the latest version of Google Play Services in your Android app unless you migrate to FCM.

Comment: You kind of contradicted yourself, if newly created GCM keys will not work post 4/11/2019 how will client SDKs continue to work indefinitely?

Comment: seems like Google has closed the GCM endpoint for sending notification in August. but getting GCM tokens as on 23 Sep 19