# GCM to FCM migration ionic v1

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an ionic v1 app. I've read and re-read the information about GCM to FCM migration, but I am still not 100% certain that my (unmigrated) app will still receive push notifications after April 11. I have migrated the server to FCM. I believe that the app should still work, but need it verified for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53853335/5832311), you need to update your client code and migrate to FCM.

> Existing deployed client-side apps receiving notifications will continue to work for the foreseeable future. But from mid-april, you:
>
> 1. won't be able to compile code using the old client-side APIs on a newer SDK/Google Play Services anymore
> 2. won't be able to call the GCM REST API to send messages anymore
>
> To compile against the new SDK/Google Play Services, you will need to make changes to your client app to migrate to Firebase Cloud Messaging from GCM. This involves changes to the `build.gradle`, to `AndroidManifest.xml` and to your code, as described in [Migrate a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm).
>
> But aside from those changes, you don't need to get new tokens for all users. The existing tokens from GCM will continue to work.