# GCM to FCM migration steps for Ionic Cordova based app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm in the middle of the migration process and have multiple questions. Apologies for that.

**Background**

- Android app is in Production and GCM based push notification service is in use.
- Have Android app developed using Ionic Cordova

**Questions**

Once I migrate Account from GCM to FCM, will the app (and push notification) still work during the migration process?

Thanks in advance.

**Answer**
Yes, I've just completed the task and the answer is yes.
But the only things I changed was the http server site which basically push the notification to the FCM rather than to GCM.

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post.

Answer (score 1):

> Once I migrate Account from GCM to FCM, will the app (and push notification) still work during the migration process?

Installations of your app that are already using GCM to receive notifications, will continue to function as before after mid-April. If you send messages through the new FCM end points/SDKs, the messages will be delivered to those apps with GCM tokens too, as long as you're sending the messages to the same Firebase project.

Comment: ~ thanks
Does that mean, once I import GCM account it does not shutdown gcm account instantly. It means the existing production system keep on working UNTIL I import and migrating the FCM stuffs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850761/do-i-need-to-migrate-gcm-to-fcm-on-client-side/53853335#53853335